# How do I merge two rows in time seriesr? (in R)

Tags: r

I want to merge two time series data sets in R.
Here are data sets below.

```
>x 
2010-01-03      A   6.0    5.2   6.1
2010-01-07      A   7.5    8.6   2.1
2010-01-11      C   5.2    4.2   2.5
2010-01-11      C   4.2    2.2   2.3
2010-01-12      B   5.2    8.0   6.0



>y
2010-01-02      d
2010-01-03      c
2010-01-04      a
2010-01-06      c
2010-01-08      b
```

And this is what I want to get as a result. (in time order)

```
2010-01-02      d
2010-01-03      A   6.0    5.2   6.1
2010-01-03      c
2010-01-04      a
2010-01-06      c
2010-01-07      A   7.5    8.6   2.1
2010-01-08      b
2010-01-11      C   5.2    4.2   2.5
2010-01-11      C   4.2    2.2   2.3
2010-01-12      B   5.2    8.0   6.0
```